# chrome and ssrs 2016 compatibility issue

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, cross-browser, ssrs-2016

we have ssrs2016 installed in windows 2012 server. 
my ssrs report have data on top of embedded image.
when i open report in IE/Edge rendering is happening fine. if i open in chrome alignment is going off. But print pdf is loading correctly. what could be the issue?

Comment: If you are using chrome browser please add below extension then it will work :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-report-fix/fjbdfjiheheafbioiejbdpalmojkeobk/related

Answer (score 0):

For SSRS Chrome compatibility you need to add below extension then it will work :
  [SSRS Chrome Compatibility](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ssrs-report-fix/fjbdfjiheheafbioiejbdpalmojkeobk/related)

Cheers !!